# aspnetcore: filenotfound exception even though assembly is referenced

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm working on an AspNetCore app. In MyClass I have the following using directive:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
```

When I added this using directive to my class, VS offered to auto-restore this package in project.json.  I clicked Yes when prompted and the following reference was added to my project.json file:

```
"System.Runtime.Serialization.Json": "4.0.1"
```

The class with this using directive has a method that uses classes/methods in the referenced assembly. The app compiles successfully. However, when this class loads at runtime, the system encounters the following exception:

```
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Platts.Bentek.Api.Maps.Services.MapsDomainService.GetFundamentalMap(Int32 reportTypeId, Int32 reportPeriodId)
   at Platts.Bentek.Api.Maps.Controllers.MapsController.FundamentalMap(Int32 reportTypeId, Int32 reportPeriodId)}
```

Any idea what the root cause of this error might be?  I have a using directive and project.json reference and the code compiles successfully.  However, this error occurs at runtime.

Comment: please add your `project.json` file in question.

Comment: Your project.json is referencing `4.0.1` but the Load Error is looking for `4.0.1.0`.  What happens if you change your project.json to reference `4.0.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I upgraded the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json package from Version 4.0.1.0 to the latest stable version (currently 4.3.0) and the error went away.